# `cherry-pick` all commits from branch

Tags: git

I have next repository state:

[image]

I have started working on `feature 1` (`feature` branch), next I have switched to `another_feature`, `addition` and `addition2` which were merged to `master`.

Now I returned to `feature` and I understand that my `feature` can not work without `addition`. What do I need to do in this case?

I cannot use `merge` because in this case I will have `another_feature` in the `feature`:

```sh
git checkout feature
git merge addition
```

I can use and it work fine:

```sh
git checkout feature
git cherry-pick 9040
```

But it is very inconvenient if I have too many commits in `addition` branch.
How can I `cherry-pick` all commits from one branch and only from this branch?

And in this case I will have `9040`-commit two times in my `master` after merge `feature`. May be there is a better way to have changes from `addition` branch in the `feature` branch?

**Addition**: after commit `feature 1` I have created Pull Request and we start to discuss it. It is very undesirable to close that PR and open the new one.

Comment: Why don't you want `another_feature` changes in `feature`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)

Comment: @mnestorov, because I have Pull Request and I don't have to see `another_feature` and many other commits to see in my Pull Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). Rebasing moves the current branch from the current base commit
to a new base commit to make sure that all work done up to now will be added to the history but starting from a different point in time.

Suppose this is your history

```
a -> b -> c : master
  \>d : feature
```

Then a rebase of feature on master will look like this

```
a -> b -> c : master
           \>d : feature
```

an in your rebased feature branche you will have commit b and c before the commit d

Mind that this is not easy if the master branch has progressed long and you may have to fix merge conflicts!

Comment: I have already opened Pull Request and `rebase` will broke my Pull Request because reviewers will see all the changes from all commits.

Comment: the reviewers will see the commits that are not in the target branch. Again suppose that commit d requires a feature in commit c then rebasing your work on c will make the code work and the difference between the master branch and the feature branch is going to be only the commit d. You may have to rewrite history also on the remote feature branch by using the `git push --force-with-lease` command or `git push --force` to make sure you can see changes on the web ui